# How to find the max continuous occurrences of an item in a list<>?

Tags: c#, list

I would like to find the max continuous occurrence of a string in a list.
Let's say I have  List where Drivers has Driver.Name, Driver.Nationality, Driver.Car
Now we have a list of races where and I store the winners in a List

I would like to see what was the most time that Ferrari wins in a row, or French drivers win in a row.

```
Drivers.add{Alex, French, Ferrari}
Drivers.add{Peter, Russian, Ferrari}
Drivers.add{John, USA, Mercedes}
Drivers.add{May, USA, Toyota}
Drivers.add{Hannah, French, Mercedes}

List<Drivers> Winners
Alex,
Peter,
Alex,
John
May,
John,
Hannah

And the results:
Max Ferrari 3
Max USA 3
```

etc.

Here is the way I tried with Color parameter. "R" is a list of the racers. It works, I am just looking for more elegant way.

```
foreach(var e in R)
{
     if (e.Color == lastColor)
     { Current++;
    if (Current > Max) { Max = Current; maxColor = e.Color; }
  }
     else { lastColor = e.Color; Current = 1; }
 }
```

Comment: Added above. I actually was looking for some elegant way. I am pretty new in c# so sorry if I am asking stupid questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in O(n) time by just using an int variable for the 'max run length' and an int variable for the 'current run length' of strings. You can iterate over your list and keep track of your current and max run lengths.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was my first question in Stack and I see I wasn't accurate enough (Sorry).. The way you mentioned is obvious, but I thought maybe there are some shorter way like the way we can count/distinct counts etc. thru the List items with LINQ. Thanks again for the answer!!

Comment: You could create your own extension method to do this so you could reuse it throughout your application. If you aren't familiar, here's more on it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693056.aspx. Your extension method could accept the target string and a string selector Func

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way as .NET doesn't have anything for grouping consecutive items.

```
var Drivers = new[] { new { Name = "Alex"  , Team = "Ferrari"  },
                      new { Name = "Peter" , Team = "Ferrari"  },
                      new { Name = "John"  , Team = "Mercedes" },
                      new { Name = "May"   , Team = "Toyota"   },
                      new { Name = "Hannah", Team = "Mercedes" } };

var Winners = "Alex Peter Alex John May John Hannah".Split();

var Teams = Winners.Join(Drivers, w => w, d => d.Name, (w, d) => d.Team);   // Ferrari, Ferrari, Ferrari, Mercedes, Toyota, Mercedes, Mercedes

var Counts = Teams.Aggregate(new List<Tuple<int, string>>(), (L, t) => { L.Add(
    Tuple.Create(L.Any() && L.Last().Item2 == t ? L.Last().Item1 + 1 : 1, t)); return L; });   // (1, Ferrari), (2, Ferrari), (3, Ferrari), (1, Mercedes), (1, Toyota), (1, Mercedes), (2, Mercedes)

var Max = Counts.Max();    // (3, Ferrari)
```

---

Custom extension methods like [MoreLinq](https://morelinq.github.io) can be used to shorten the Aggregate part:

```
var Max = Teams.GroupAdjacent(t => t).MaxBy(g => g.Count());

Debug.Print("Max " + Max.Key + " " + Max.Count()); // "Max Ferrari 3"
```